# How to do a case-insensitive string where in NHibernate Linq query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate

How to do a case-insensitive where in NHibernate  Linq query?

e.g.

```
//note this one doesn't work if the entry in database has lowercase
q => q.Where(entity => 
    entity.CaseInsensitiveField == DesiredField.Trim().ToUpper())
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try this:

```
q => q.Where(entity => entity.CaseInsensitiveField.ToUpper() == DesiredField.Trim().ToUpper())
```

Also, I would suggest to set the parameter outside the query:

```
var value = DesiredField.Trim().ToUpper();

...

q => q.Where(entity => entity.CaseInsensitiveField.ToUpper() == value)
```

Comment: Yes it will, as the ToUpper() method will be translated as UPPER(field) in your SQL query.

Comment: ivowiblo: I humbly confess you were right, my ContainsLike method will not be translated into SQL. Please see my comment to my answer for further details. Thanks to you, with all my humility.

Answer (score 5):

Use this:

```
q => q.Where(entity => 
    String.Equals(entity.CaseInsensitiveField , CaseInsensitiveField , 
                  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

UPDATE

It appears (at least via LinqPad) that the above will not translate into SQL, so I would suggest, as ivowiblo has already suggested:

```
var comparisonValue = CaseInsensitiveField.ToUpper();
q => q.Where(entity => 
    entity.CaseInsensitiveField.ToUpper() == comparisonValue);
```

The reason to set the ToUpper beforehand is that procedural functions are generally worse in SQL, and since this is not a database field, we can send it in already capitalized.

Comment: `string.Equals` or `entity.CaseInsensitiveField ==` are the same, so yes it is translated as a simple comparison just like you do.

Comment: Actually, I just updated my answer. LinqPad is saying this will not translate into SQL. So, I updated my response. It ends up being the same as ivowiblo, however I provided the reasoning for the breaking out of the variable

Comment: Thanks for mentioning LINQPad, I just tried it and I now know how to determine what can and cannot be translated to SQL.

Comment: Note: LINQPad doesn't use NHibernate, which the question is asking for.